# how to get values using regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

here is my sample code

```
import re

string = '[P-123,SHA-123]'
pattern = re.compile(r"^\[(?P<curve>).*\]$", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.search(string)
print(result)
```

**Expected output:**
`P-123`

Comment: What problem you faced ? Please mention that too. It'll help the community in providing you the help.If you want that only p should precede any digit combination; you may use `(?i)p-\d+`

Comment: Why do you expect that output? Your regex specifically says to match everything up through the right square bracket and the end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match that data format:

```
^\[(?P<curve>[A-Z]-\d+),[A-Z]+-\d+]\Z
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?P<curve>` Named capture group `curve`

  - `[A-Z]-\d+` Match a single uppercase char, `-` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `,[A-Z]+-\d+` Match 1+ uppercase chars `-` and 1+ digits
- `]` Match `]`
- `\Z` End of string (or use `$` if a newline after is allowed)

The value is in named capturing group `curve`. You could also use re.match instead of re.search as you are looking for a single group in the whole string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nl2qLM/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Olt7tg)

*Example code*

```
import re

string = '[P-123,SHA-123]'
pattern = re.compile(r"\[(?P<curve>[A-Z]-\d+),[A-Z]+-\d+]\Z", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.match(string)
print(result.group("curve"))
```

*Output*

```
P-123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '[P-123,SHA-123]'
pattern = re.compile(r"(P.\d*)", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.search(string)
print(result[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex `\W([A-Z]-[0-9]*)` that extracting capital letter follow by - and then numbers

```
import re

string = '[P-123,SHA-123]'
pattern = re.compile(r"\W([A-Z]-[0-9]*)", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.search(string).group(1)
print(result)
```

Output

```
P-123
```